# Date count, what do i do wrong?

Tags: php, date

Today I began with a day counter but ran into a problem; I need to substract the database date from the today date:

```
     <?php



     $query = "SELECT reparatie.reparatieid, reparatie.klantid, klant.achternaam, reparatie.afgerond FROM reparatie INNER JOIN klant ON reparatie.klantid=klant.klantid";



        $result = $link->query($query);



        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print("<tr>");
        print("<td>".$row ["reparatieid"]."</td>"." ");
        print("<td>".$row ["klantid"]."</td>"." ");
        print("<td>".$row ["achternaam"]."</td>"." ");
        print("<td>".$row ["afgerond"]."</td>"." ");

        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin'); 

        $date1 = ["afgerond"];      
        $date2 = date_create('TODAY');
        $interval = date_diff($date1, $date2);
        print$interval;


        print("<td>". "<input type='submit' name='open' value='open'/><form></td>"."<br>");

        print("</tr>");

        }
        } else {
        echo "0 results";}
        print("</table>");

        mysqli_free_result($result);
        mysqli_close($link);

        ?>
```

but it gives this error message:

```
Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, array given
```

Can someone help me with this code?

Comment: Typo: `$date1 = ["afgerond"];` ⇒ `$date1 = $row["afgerond"];`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! it now says:  date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$date1 = ["afgerond"];` is an `array()` not a `date`. [`date_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) function is an alias of: [DateTime::diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php). It required two parameters, both should be date. You can try this if `$row ["afgerond"]` is a date.

```
    $date1 = date_create($row["afgerond"]);
    $date2 = date_create('TODAY');
    $interval  = date_diff($date1,$date2);
    print $interval->format("%R%a days");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $date1 = date_create($row["afgerond"]);      
    $date2 = date_create('TODAY');
    $interval = date_diff($date1, $date2);
    print_r($interval);
```

This should give you the expected result.